# Why do I end up at the console login instead of the graphical desktop?

Tags: 12.04, login

I don't think this is the usual login for Ubuntu. [image: http://i.imgur.com/15qSc.jpg]

Comment: Um, no, that doesn't seem right.  What happens if you login as it asks?  I am assuming, too, that this comes up every time, right?

Comment: When I login it just shows all the commands of the login sequence I assume, but no actual graphics or anything comes up, and yes this comes up every time. I usually just go in 'recovery mode' then go to Normal Boot and then everything went smoothly. But, now it just does this everytime.

Comment: If your computer is connected via ethernet (not wireless), I would try running `sudo apt-get update&&sudo apt-get upgrade`. What happens if you press ctrl+alt+f7(ctrl+alt+f1 should get you back to that prompt)?

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in with your username & password then use the following command :

```
startx
```

Comment: I would run `sudo service lightdm start` which should get them to the login. If it doesn't there are some serious problems with the driver (which is what this looks like).

Comment: Didn't do anything...

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with the driver, i've logged on before.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching over to tty7? Desktop environments (like Unity) usually start there. Try Ctrl+Alt+7 and see what happens.

Comment: Nothing happens at all..

Comment: What hardware setup do you have? If you have switchable graphics, this can be solved with some BIOS work. Please give some basic specs.

Comment: I have a NVIDIA GeForce 6150 LE with integrate graphics and OpenGL 2.1. It's fairly old, 2003 I think. Asus A8M2N-LA (NodusM) Motherboard. 512 MB RAM.

Comment: Unity and NVIDIA have a history of disliking each other. Try booting using your integrated graphics card and see if it gives you the desktop.